# How to fetch specific schedule in fullcalendar-codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I've been bugging by this problem for like 2 weeks already, and I can't seem to find the reason why it is not working.

In my database, I have a table called 'course' where the user can add courses with schedule.

Problem: The problem is the calendar in my "edit course" page shows all the schedule of the courses stored in the table. What I want is when I want to edit the info of a specific course, the calendar should only display the schedule of that course.

My calendar shows all the schedule of all courses

[image]

Here is my controller function:

```
public function load()
{
  $event_data = $this->crud_model->fetch_all_event();

  foreach($event_data->result_array() as $row)
  {
   $data[] = array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'title' => $row['sched_desc'],
    'start' => $row['start'],
    'end' => $row['end']
   );
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Model function:

```
public function fetch_all_event($course_id = "")
{
    $this->db->order_by('id');
    $this->db->select("*");
    return $this->db->get('course');
}
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable:false,
            header:{
                left:'prev,next today',
                center:'title',
                right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/load"  
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my attempt but failed to work:

```
public function fetch_all_event($course_id)
{
    $course_details = $this->get_course_by_id($course_id)->row_array();
    $id = $course_details['id'];

    $this->db->order_by('id');
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->get('course');
}

public function get_course_by_id($course_id = "")
{
    return $this->db->get_where('course', array('id' => $course_id));
}
```

I hope someone here can help me, thank you.

Comment: Somehow you need to pass the course ID into the load() method. From your description so far, it's not clear where that ID comes from. Does the View which loads the "edit course" page and shows the calendar know the ID of the course? If so, then you could inject it into the events URL which fullCalendar is requesting.

Comment: Hi, may i know how can I pass the courseID in to the load() method?

Comment: That's literally what I described in my comment already - you have to make it part of the URL which fullCalendar is calling.